# Accelerometer turn in background service

Tags: android, background, accelerometer

I used this link http://blog.androgames.net/85/android-accelerometer-tutorial/ to create an accelerometer. But I want that this accelerometer work in the background. So I changed the code like this:

```
public class Accelerometer extends Service implements AccelerometerListener{
private static Context CONTEXT;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
// TODO Put your code here
return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
System.out.println(”start listening”);
// if (AccelerometerManager.isSupported()) {
AccelerometerManager.startListening(this);

// }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
System.out.println(”start listening”);
// if (AccelerometerManager.isListening()) {
AccelerometerManager.stopListening();
// }
}

public static Context getContext() {
return CONTEXT;
}

/**
* onShake callback
*/
public void onShake(float force) {
Toast.makeText(this, “close” + force, 1000).show();
}

/**
* onAccelerationChanged callback
*/
public void onAccelerationChanged(float x, float y, float z) {
System.out.println(”x = “+x+” y = “+y+” z = “+z);
}

}
```

And I obtained this error:

```
 Java.lang.runtimeexception : Unable to create service com.tam.Accelerometer: java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: java;lang.NullPointerException
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: can you add the whole stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Android Accelerometer Sensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608372/android-accelerometer-sensor/6609401#6609401)
You already posted it and got an answer if that is you?  You need to set CONTEXT

```
this.getApplicationContext()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign CONTEXT value as

```
CONTEXT = Accelerometer.this;
```

in `onCreate()` method