# what is the method for count the picking phone

Tags: android, accelerometer, shake

I need to calculate how many times user picking the phone from pocket or table. I know the accelerometer. But is it a right way to do or any other methods available?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Light Sensor](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html) but most old device haven't it.

Or `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` + `TYPE_PROXIMITY` for understand if the phone is pick out for responde to a phone call or is only moved.

Comment: But i need to count while my phone is picking from table. So, can i use Accelerometer z axis? If z axis beyond some value shall i call count method?

Comment: of course.
You must implement your [accelerometer like a service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608372/android-accelerometer-sensor/6609401#6609401) and `onAccelerationChanged` you can store your data or send a `sendBroadcast(intent)`.
This function is like the gesture's recognition.

Comment: I didn't understand. I referred this link for accelerometer http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/a-quick-tutorial-on-coding-androids-accelerometer/ I'm getting z axis value, then how can i store the number of z axis value and count?

Comment: 1) you can store the value in a [sql lite database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) [this is a nice tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) or in a [sharedpreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)
2) if you have to listen the accelerometer also when your app isn't in foreground you must implement an [android service 'started'](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)